# CloudFront returning 403 instead of 404 for missing pages from S3 using OAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Using AWS CloudFormation I set up a CloudFront distribution to serve content from a private S3 bucket. I do *not* have the bucket configured as an S3 website — rather, I'm using the [latest-and-greatest](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-origin-access-control-oac/) technique: Origin Access Control (OAC). See [Restricting access to an Amazon S3 origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html). I'm using Route53 and Certificate Manager to serve the CloudFront distribution over TLS with a custom domain `example.com`.

So far the basics are working fine for URLs that reference objects that exist in the S3 bucket. I can access https://example.com/foobar.html just fine, for example. But if I request a file that does not exist, such as https://example.com/missing.html, CloudFront returns a `403` "Access Denied" instead of a `404` "Not Found".

I can make a wild guess that some communication between CloudFront and S3 makes CloudFront think its access is denied if the object doesn't exist. (Still that doesn't explain *why*.) Is this a bug? Is this expected behavior? How are we expected to use CloudFront+S3+OAC with this odd behavior—does AWS expect us to set up a [CloudFront custom error response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-customerrorresponse.html) to convert `403` to `404`? (But why would we want to assume all access denied errors in CloudFormation really indicate a missing object on S3?)

Note that I found various other CloudFront questions related to `403`, but none related to an OAC configuration, and most of the other questions were regarding a CloudFront distribution that *always* returned 403, not just for missing files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have the `s3:ListBucket` permission, S3 returns the `403 Forbidden` status and the `AccessDenied` error for missing objects, by design.  This is because without `s3:ListBucket`, the principal doesn't have permission to know whether the object is missing or if it exists but they aren't allowed access.

Note that unlike `s3:GetObject`, an object-level permission where the resource ARN is `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*`, `s3:ListBucket` is a bucket-level permission, so the resource is `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name` without the trailing `/*`.

After updating the bucket policy, you should find that the 404s work as expected, but you also need to set the Cloudfront Default Root Object for the distribution to whatever you want returned when `/` is requested, otherwise a bucket listing will be returned, which is probably not what you want.

Also be aware of the Error Caching Minimum TTL, which causes CloudFront to cache those 403s for 5 minutes, separate from the other TTL settings for the cache behavior.

Comment: Ah, something like [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775442). That did the trick! Thank you for the spot-on answer as well as the additional useful details.

Comment: "… you also need to set the Cloudfront Default Root Object for the distribution …, otherwise a bucket listing will be returned, which is probably not what you want." Ah, now I understand why the `DefaultCacheBehavior` `DefaultRootObject` only applies to `/`, because its primary purpose must be to prevent listing the bucket contents—and the bucket namespace is flat, not hierarchical, so without this setting it would result in a listing of _all_ bucket names.

Comment: @GarretWilson it wouldn't list all the buckets, it would just list the contents of the one the distribution is pointing to. The official purpose of `DefaultRootObject` is to allow you to treat `/` as `/index.html` or something similar and replace the bucket listing with something else.  If I remember right, it's been available since before the S3 web site hosting feature was rolled out, with more proper index document support, a few years ago.

Comment: It's long been my belief that the name of the `s3:ListBucket` privilege is essentially a design mistake that it's way too late to fix. The more correct and intuitive name of this privilege would have been `s3:ListObjects`, because that's what it allows.  Similarly, `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` would have been more correctly called `s3:ListBuckets`, 
since that's the one that allows fetching a list of buckets in your account... but it wasn't.

Comment: "… it wouldn't list all the buckets …" Yes I understand. By "all bucket names" I meant "the names of all objects in the bucket" (not the best choice of words on my part). Because the namespace is flat, this will list _all_ object in the bucket; furthermore a default root object will help `/`, but not `/foo/` or `/foo/bar/`. But a default root object will hide the directory listing of all the bucket objects. Anyway see my answer for a more comprehensive solution using functions, based upon the information you alerted me to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is exactly correct. I'm leaving a separate answer here just to flesh out the details of exactly what needs to be done. I'll use CloudFormation for illustration.

Here's an example of updating the S3 bucket policy to include `s3:GetObject`:

```yaml
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:ListBucket
            Resource: !Sub "${Bucket.Arn}"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                AWS:SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFrontDistribution}"
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudfront.amazonaws.com
            Action: s3:GetObject
            Resource: !Sub "${Bucket.Arn}/*"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                AWS:SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cloudfront::${AWS::AccountId}:distribution/${CloudFrontDistribution}"
```

As Michael mentioned, you need to set `DefaultRootObject` to something or CloudFront will return a directory listing when `/` is requested. But you still need to indicate a default page if any sub-path root is indicated, such as `/foo/bar/`. And what if you don't want to indicate a default page? You can address both issues using CloudFront functions.

First set up a parameter for the default page:

```yaml
Parameters:
  DefaultPage:
    Description: The default page, such as `index.html`.
    Type: String
    Default: index.html
```

Then set up the function:

```yaml
  DefaultPageFunction:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Function
    Properties:
      Name: default-page
      AutoPublish: true
      FunctionConfig:
        Comment: Convert root requests to default page.
        Runtime: cloudfront-js-1.0
      FunctionCode: !Sub |
        function handler(event) {
          var request = event.request;
          var uri = request.uri;
          if (uri.endsWith("/")) {
            var defaultPage = "${DefaultPage}";
            if(defaultPage) {
              request.uri += defaultPage;
            } else {
              return {
                statusCode: 403,
                statusDescription: "Forbidden"
              };
            }
          }
          return request;
        }
```

This function handles both cases based upon the `DefaultPage` parameter. If it's set to a non-empty string, it will add that to any `…/` path. If `DefaultPage` is empty, then it will return an HTTP `403` `Forbidden` for every `…/` path.

Finally add it to your `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` `DefaultCacheBehavior`:

```yaml
          …
          FunctionAssociations:
            - EventType: viewer-request
              FunctionARN: !GetAtt DefaultPageFunction.FunctionMetadata.FunctionARN
        DefaultRootObject: !Ref DefaultPage
```

I threw in the `DefaultRootObject` for good measure, even though the function should take care of that case as well.

*Warning!* There seems to be a bug with CloudFormation that will get the parameter "stuck" with one value, so double-check that CloudFormation deployed the correct value if you modify `DefaultPage` after deploying. See the ticket I just opened:  [CloudFormation `deploy` doesn't update `!Sub` contents with new parameter value. #989](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-cli/issues/989)