# I can upload files to S3 bucket using AWS console but not with CLI. How to upload files to S3 bucket through CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I can successfully upload the file from AWS console (UI) to the S3 bucket, but when I try to upload the file from my CLI using command:

```
aws s3 sync d1/ s3://<s3-bucket>/test-directory
```

I am getting this error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2
> operation: Access Denied

Comment: What are the permissions of the AWS credentials you are using with the awscli?

Comment: You can check what credentials are being used in the AWS CLI by running the `aws iam get-user` command (with no additional parameters). This will show you which IAM entity is being used by the AWS CLI to make API calls to AWS. Based on the behaviour you describe, it is likely that this will be a different user that the one you use to login to the AWS management console.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. The issue was that I had specified policy for the objects but not for the bucket itself.

Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775442/12833440